# Deleting the maximum value of a numeric variable in SAS

Tags: syntax, sas, max, delete-row

I have a data set where I want to delete the maximum year (which is 2014 right now). I search for a syntax where I can delete this maximum year in the data set without having to write if year=2014 then delete - because I don't want to correct it manually when 2015 becomes the new maximum year.

I have tried something like:

```
data new;
set old;
if max(year) then delete;
run;
```

and

```
data new;
set old;
if year=max(year) then delete;
run;
```

Bu it does not work - the max function don't seem to be the right way to go?

Kind Regards 
Maria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or in PROC SQL...

```
proc sql ;
  select max(year(DATE)) into :YR from old ;
  delete from old where year(DATE) >= &YR ;
quit ;
```

Creating a new table instead of deleting from old table...

```
proc sql ;
  select max(year(DATE)) into :YR from old ;
  create table new as select * from old where year(DATE) lt &YR ;
quit ;
```

Comment: Like this, very elegant

Comment: I tried your version - it found it more intuitive for me to use: But it comes with this error in the log: ERROR: Expression using greater than or equal (>=) has components that are of different data types.                                                   I changed your syntax into my own variable names and data set name: proc sql ;
    select max(aargang) into :YR from staa_kum2 ;
    delete from staa_kum2 where aargang >= &YR ;
    quit ;

Comment: now I added a data step in stead of th edelte line:             proc sql ;
    select max(aargang) into :YR from staa_kum2 ;
    quit ;
 data test;
 set staa_kum2;
 if aargang >= &YR then delete;
 run; - and it works.

Comment: Or do it all in PROC SQL, but with a create table statement... edited to show example. Your ERROR is likely due to the fact that `aargang` is not a SAS date, it's a text value - convert it to a proper SAS date at source.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is because aargang is a character variable. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

SAS works line by line. Because of this you will need a datastep that first pulls out the max date, and then a second datastep where those rows which contain that date are deleted. For example:

```
data Max_Date (keep = max_date);
 set original_dataset end = eof;
 retain max_date;
 if date > max_date then max_date = date;
 if eof then do;
    output;
 end;
run;
```

Put the max date into a macro variable then use this to delete the appropriate records

Answer (score 0):

Maria,

If the max date is always going to be the current year for what you are trying to do, you can always write a macro at the beginning to grab the current year to use in a comparison for deleting from your dataset.

```
    %let numdate = %sysfunc(today(), date9.);
    %let Max_year = %substr(&numdate,6,4);
    %put todays date is &numdate;
    %put max year is &Max_year;
```

Result from log:

```
461  %let numdate = %sysfunc(today(), date9.);
462  %let Max_year = %substr(&numdate,6,4);
463  %put todays date is &numdate;
todays date is 15APR2014
464  %put max year is &Max_year;
max year is 2014
```

**Then the code you had comparing with the macro created should do the job.**

```
 data new;
    set old;
    if year = &Max_year then delete;
 run;
```